# Is is possible to make a batch file that can run before the user logs in?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is is possible to run a batch file before a user has logged in? I want to play a music file when the computer boots up. Is this possible? I want to do it strictly with batch files.

Answer (score 1):

You want a Scheduled Task using the Windows Task Scheduler.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx

Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Task Scheduler.

Create a task that runs "On Startup" as trigger and without requiring a user account.

[image]
[image]

As for "what program" to run to play music without an active desktop session, I'm not sure.  You probably want a command line player.  Do an internet search for one.  ffmpeg might be able to do it from within a command line bat file.

Comment: You can make a batch/VBScript hybrid to play an audio file.